# Unresolved attribute reference '...' for class '...'

Tags: python, pygame, pycharm

When I call the render() method in the Zombie class, I want to add an instance of the Zombie object into ZombieList.list. When I try to do this, it says

> Unresolved attribute reference `list` for class `ZombieList`.

Should I try to do this another way?

```
class ZombieList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.list = []
        for zombie in self.list:
            ds.blit(zombie.image, (1000, random.randint(10, 790)))

class Zombie(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.attack = 3
        self.speed = 5
        self.health = 30
        self.image = pygame.image.load("Assets/green zombie.png")

        self.zombieList = []

    def render(self):
        ZombieList.list.append(self)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot append to a list of a class. You need to append to an *instance* of a class. For instance:

```
class ZombieList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.list = []
        for zombie in self.list:
            ds.blit(zombie.image, (1000, random.randint(10, 790)))

my_zombie_list = ZombieList() # create an instance

class Zombie(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.attack = 3
        self.speed = 5
        self.health = 30
        self.image = pygame.image.load("Assets/green zombie.png")

        self.zombieList = []

    def render(self):
        my_zombie_list.list.append(self) # refer to the previously created instance
```

Answer (score 1):

You've to create a `ZombieList` object, where you can append the `Zombie` objects to.
You can add a [Class Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) to to the class `Zombie`:

```
class Zombie(object):

    zombies = ZombieList()

    def __init__(self):
        self.attack = 3
        self.speed = 5
        self.health = 30
        self.image = pygame.image.load("Assets/green zombie.png")

    def render(self):
        Zombie.zombies.list.append(self)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no attribute `list` in `ZombieList`. Only once you've created a `ZombieList` through e.g. `self.zombie_list = ZombieList()` will you be able to make use of your list through `self.zombie_list.list`.

Even then, though, I imagine this probably isn't the design you're aiming for: I imagine that you don't want a `ZombieList` for each individual `Zombie`. Rather, whoever is initializing the `Zombie` objects should probably be in charge of maintaining the `ZombieList` instance as well.

You will also run into other issues. For example, the loop in

```
self.list = []
for zombie in self.list:
    ds.blit(zombie.image, (1000, random.randint(10, 790)))
```

will never have any effect since `self.list` is always empty when that code is executed (since you've defined it to be empty on the previous line).